# How do I separate a dictionary that has two keys into two seperate new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using Pandas and I have a column that has a dictionary with two keys (a'11' and a'10').

This is what I have

```
Id  (dictionary1, dictionary2)
0   {a'11': [a'255', a'258'], a'10': [a'224', a'222']}  
1   {a'11': [a'262', a'261'], a'10': [a'214', a'212']}  
2   {a'11': [a'241', a'238'], a'10': [a'244', a'202']}
```

I need to separate this column into two new columns, one with the a'10' values and one with the a'11' values.

What would be the correct code for doing this?

Comment: How can `a'10'` be a key?

Comment: What is `a'11'`, etc.? This notation is illegal in Python.

Comment: How do I get rid of the 'a' in front of every key and value to get the correct notation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str` accessor to index over a `Series` containing iterables:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[{'a': 1, 'b':2}], [{'a': 3, 'b': 4}]], columns=['d'])

print(df, '\n')
print(df['d'].str['a'])
```

Output:

```
                  d
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1  {'a': 3, 'b': 4} 

0    1
1    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tolist` with `DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.d.tolist())
           10          11
0  [224, 222]  [255, 258]
1  [224, 222]  [255, 258]
2  [224, 222]  [255, 258]
```